# How to get price of correct date from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have following MySQL table:

```
---+-------+------------+----------
id | price | e_date     | item_name
---+-------+------------+----------
 1 | 1000  | 2015-01-01 | pen
 2 | 1050  | 2015-02-01 | pen
 3 | 800   | 2015-03-01 | pen
 4 | 850   | 2015-03-20 | pen
 5 | 1150  | 2015-04-01 | pen
 6 | 500   | 2015-01-01 | pencil
 7 | 550   | 2015-02-01 | pencil
 8 | 700   | 2015-03-01 | pencil
---+-------+------------+----------
```

I want to get price of different days.
Suppose I want to get price of `2015-02-15`, then price will be `1050`.
I want to get price of `2015-03-15`, then price will be `800`.

I used following query:

```
SELECT max(price) FROM table_name WHERE e_date<$date
```

Here `$date` comes from user input (suppose user input `2015-03-15`).

But as `max` is used, price is returning as `1050` on `2015-03-15` which should be `800`.

How can I get the right price by a single query and without using sub-query (if possible)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select price
from table_name
where e_date <= $user_date
order by e_date desc
limit 1;
```

If you have an index on e_date and price, your query will not even need to hit the table.

**Get highest price on or immediately before the supplied date**

```
select price
from table_name
where e_date <= $user_date
order by e_date desc, price desc
limit 1;
```

The above query sorts all records before the current date by date and price. If user_date was 2015-02-15 and there were multiple products, the query will sort all data by date and price and choose the closest date first and highest price second. This may or may not work for your efforts.

**Get highest price in the current month**

```
select price
from table_name
where e_date between date_format($user_date,'%Y-%m-01') and $user_date
order by price desc
limit 1;
```

This query pulls all records between beginning of the month through user provided date. Then it orders by highest pricing first and shows the highest price.

**Get highest price by item in the current month**

```
select item_name, max(price) as max_price
from table_name
where e_date between date_format($user_date,'%Y-%m-01') and $user_date
group by item_name
order by max_price;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ce19/9

**Get price closest to the date (before or after)**

```
select price from
(
  (select *, datediff($user_date, e_date) as days 
  from table_name where e_date <= $user_date
  order by e_date desc, price desc
  limit 1)
  union
  (select *, datediff(e_date, $user_date) as days 
  from table_name where e_date >= $user_date
  order by e_date, price desc
  limit 1)
) closest
order by days, price desc
limit 1;
```

In the query above, we find 1 record before the date and 1 record after the given date. We calculate the days between the dates and report price for the closest date. If there are two closest days, we additionally sort by price.

Alternate version:

```
select price
from test
order by abs(datediff(e_date, '2015-02-15')), price desc
limit 1;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ce19/19 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ce19/21

Comment: It will work only if there is only one item (like pen) in the database. In case of more items (like pencil, eraser etc) how your query works? It will return only one item if use limit 1

Comment: I added more item in my sample database table. Please look at my sample table now.

Comment: Let me put a couple of examples together in a few minutes.

Comment: Added some examples to get closer to your needs

Comment: Your last solution works perfect (which query you given in sqlfiddle). But I need to test it in various price and date situation. I will accept your solution obviously if it can return correct price in all the situation after testing. Thannks.

Comment: These answers are guidelines to solving your own questions. I'd recommend that you tweak these queries to your needs instead of me providing exact answers to your changing requirements.

Comment: No, your solution is working here because max price is given at later date (in my sample table, 800 in 2015-03-01 and 850 in 2015-03-20). If you change the data like 850 in 2015-03-01 and 800 in 2015-03-20 and query for price on 2015-03-21, then price is returning as 850 on 2015-03-21. It is because you actually returning max price for a particular month which is not our goal

Comment: But the guideline is not useful, because it is returning max price, but I need actual price (which may be either maximum or minimum)

Comment: In both version, it is returning price for only one item (for pen), but there is one more item (pencil) in the database. It is because when you use limit clause in a query, it will limit the result for whole query, it can't differentiate items.

Comment: I am sorry for not being able to understand your requirements. I'll leave my answer as-is in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Ok, I will post a new topic later. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to just query using the year and month as follows:

```
SELECT max(price) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE YEAR(e_date) = $year AND MONTH(e_date) = $month 
group by YEAR(e_date), MONTH(e_date);
```

Or you could use:

```
SELECT max(price) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE YEAR(e_date) = YEAR($date) AND MONTH(e_date) = MONTH($date) 
group by YEAR(e_date), MONTH(e_date);
```

Comment: It is working great, but isn't any other way to get it? If no other suitable answer found, I will accept your answer. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: I found one demerit of your code. Let I have more than one price for a particular month (suppose for March'15), Then how your code will work, because there are more than one price for march'15. I have added the price in my sample table. Please look at the table now. Thanks

Comment: I've added a second option for you as well.

Comment: not working either. It is returning 850 on 2015-03-15

Comment: Sorry, then your question is not clear enough. I thought you were wanting to get the maximum price for a particular month of a particular date.

Comment: No, I want the actual price which falls in between given user date and the closest date (higer or lower) in the database